# Recursive erase hidden files

Tags: macos, unix

I'm trying to recursive erase all files that begin with "._" (aka mac dot files) on my server using SSH.
The files are listed with a ls -a but this won't work:

```
rm -rf ._*
```

I know there's a way. Mind to share? 
Cheers!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`find . -name ._\* -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f`

Comment: Yeap, I was removing these files manually via FTP but the thing have toooo many subdirectories so a recursive remove via ssh is THE thing to do :) 
Thank you anyway, is done now, you saved me HOURS of browsing and clicking like a goddamn animal. Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

```
find . -name ._\* -type f -delete
```

Specify that it's files and just call the find-delete on item directly.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name ._\* -exec rm -f {} \;
```

by the way rm -rf is for removing **directories recursively**